# proving that $\frac{1}{\sqrt a + \sqrt b} +\frac{1}{\sqrt b + \sqrt c} + \frac{1}{\sqrt c + \sqrt d} = \frac{3}{\sqrt a + \sqrt d} $ for any A.P.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, radicals, fractions, arithmetic-progressions

**if $a,b,c,d$ are an arithmetic progression (in that order), prove that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt a + \sqrt b} +\frac{1}{\sqrt b + \sqrt c} + \frac{1}{\sqrt c + \sqrt d} = \frac{3}{\sqrt a + \sqrt d}  $$**

I made $n$ the common difference of $a,b,c,d$; so
$$a=a$$
$$b=a +n$$
$$c=a + 2n$$
$$d=a+3n$$
I tried to replace the terms with those, anyways i squared both equalities but i didn 't get nothing since i'm pretty bad with square roots. I'm looking for some hints or properties that can be useful. Thanks

Comment: don't square. Try to rationalize: remember that 
$$(\sqrt y -\sqrt x)(\sqrt y +\sqrt x) = y-x $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HINT

Multiply and divide by conjugate of each denominator, then you'll get a $(-n)$ in each denominator.

Then :
$$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}~+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c}~+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{d} \over {-n}$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{a} -\sqrt{d}}{-n}=\frac{a-d}{-n \cdot (\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{d})}= \frac{3}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{d}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt a + \sqrt b} +\frac{1}{\sqrt b + \sqrt c} + \frac{1}{\sqrt c + \sqrt d} =\frac{1}{n}(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{c}-\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{d}-\sqrt{c})=$$
$$=\frac{d-a}{n(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{d})}= \frac{3}{\sqrt a + \sqrt d} $$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt a + \sqrt b} +\frac{1}{\sqrt b + \sqrt c} + \frac{1}{\sqrt c + \sqrt d} = \frac{3}{\sqrt a + \sqrt d}
$

Make into A.P.

$S
=\frac{1}{\sqrt a + \sqrt {a+x}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt {a+x} + \sqrt {a+2x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt {a+2x} + \sqrt {a+3x}} 
- \frac{3}{\sqrt a + \sqrt {a+3x}}
$

Rationalize

$\frac{1}{\sqrt a + \sqrt {a+x}}\frac{\sqrt a - \sqrt {a+x}}{\sqrt a - \sqrt {a+x}}
=\frac{\sqrt a - \sqrt {a+x}}{-x}
$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt {a+x} + \sqrt {a+2x}}\frac{\sqrt {a+x} - \sqrt {a+2x}}{\sqrt {a+x} - \sqrt {a+2x}}
=\frac{\sqrt {a+x} - \sqrt {a+2x}}{-x}
$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt {a+2x} + \sqrt {a+3x}}\frac{\sqrt {a+2x} - \sqrt {a+3x}}{\sqrt {a+2x} - \sqrt {a+3x}}
=\frac{\sqrt {a+2x} - \sqrt {a+3x}}{-x}
$

$\frac{3}{\sqrt a + \sqrt {a+3x}}\frac{\sqrt a - \sqrt {a+3x}}{\sqrt a - \sqrt {a+3x}}
=\frac{3\sqrt a -3 \sqrt {a+3x}}{-3x}
=\frac{\sqrt a - \sqrt {a+3x}}{-x}
$

Combine

$\begin{array}\\
S
&= (-1/x)
((\sqrt a - \sqrt {a+x})
+(\sqrt {a+x} - \sqrt {a+2x})\\
&\qquad +(\sqrt {a+2x} - \sqrt {a+3x})
-(\sqrt a - \sqrt {a+3x}))\\
&= 0
\qquad\text{because everything cancels out!!!}\\
\end{array}
$